# correlation within a limited range

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, range

How does one interpret a correlation that does not appear until an asymptotic point? For example, in the graph below?[image]

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "interpret."  Ordinarily that would be a meaningful explanation of data behavior, but since you don't tell us what these data are, you must have something else in mind.  Could you also explain what you mean by an "asymptotic point"?

Comment: Hi @whuber. It's hard to give context, but you can imagine the x-axis is a self-confidence and y-axis is how many flips you make in your decision making. It appears that once you reach a certain amount of self-confidence, there is a negative linear relationship with flips, but not before. The asymptote being that point (not a good choice of word)

Answer (score 0):

One could simply say that the relation between $Y$ and $X$ is non-linear. Maybe a different relation $Y=f(X)$ should be used, such as a [segmented regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression), for instance. It depends on the assumptions you are able to make, depending on your knowledge about your data.